# How do I set initial state to data fetched with useQuery?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo

I'm working with React and Apollo and I'm trying to initialize state with data fetched using useQuery hook but I'm getting "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" when loading the page.

```js
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(FETCH_BLOGS);
const [state, setState] = useState(undefined);

useEffect(() => {
  if (loading === false && data) {
    setState(data.blogs);
  }
}, [loading, data]);

if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;  
if (error) return <p>Error</p>;
```

In the JSX I'm calling `{renderBlogs(state)}` which maps over the array and is where the error is being thrown. If I pass in the initial data `{renderBlogs(data.blogs)}` it works but I need to store the data in state as it will be mutated.

When I `console.log(state)` it logs 2 lines:

- The first is `undefined`.
- The second is the array of blogs (as shown in the screenshot).

[image: screenshot console log]

It appears that the page is trying to render the initial state (`undefined`) before before the state is set to the query data. Is this the case? I thought using `useEffect` would solve this but that doesn't seem to be the case. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To quote the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) documentation:

> The function passed to `useEffect` will run after the render is committed to the screen. Think of effects as an escape hatch from React’s purely functional world into the imperative world.

The problem is that `useEffect` will trigger **after** a render. This will result in the following chain of events. Assume `loading` is just set to `false` and there where no errors fetching the data.

When the component is now being rendered both the `if (loading)` and `if (error)` guard clauses will be skipped, because the data successfully loaded. However `state` is not yet updated because the `useEffect` callback will trigger after the current render. At this point when you call `renderBlogs(state)` `state` will still be `undefined`. This will trow the error you describe.

I might be missing some context, but from what is shown in the question there is no reason to use `useEffect`. Instead use `data` directly.

The example provided by Apollo for [`useQuery`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#usequery) provides a good starting point:

> ```
> import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
>
> const GET_GREETING = gql`
>   query GetGreeting($language: String!) {
>     greeting(language: $language) {
>       message
>     }
>   }
> `;
>
> function Hello() {
>   const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_GREETING, {
>     variables: { language: 'english' },
>   });
>   if (loading) return <p>Loading ...</p>;
>   return <h1>Hello {data.greeting.message}!</h1>;
> }
> ```

Applying the example to your scenario it might look very similar.

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(FETCH_BLOGS);

if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;  
if (error) return <p>Error</p>;

return renderBlogs(data.blogs);
```

---

If you need the setter you might want to provide a bit more context to the question. However a common reason to have a setter might be if you want to apply some sort of filter. A simple solution would be to have a computed blogs state.

```
const filteredBlogs = data.blogs.filter(blog => blog.title.includes(search));
```

Here `search` would be the state of some `<input value={search} onChange={handleSearchChange} />` element. To improve performance you could also opt to use [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) here.

```
const filteredBlogs = useMemo(() => (
  data.blogs.filter(blog => blog.title.includes(search))
), [data.blogs, search]);
```

---

If you really need to use `useState` for some reason, you could try the `onCompleted` option of `useQuery` instead of `useEffect`.

```
const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState();
const { loading, error } = useQuery(FETCH_BLOGS, {
  onCompleted: data => setBlogs(data.blogs),
});
```

Comment: I have ```if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;``` below useEffect. Still no luck. Edited original post for clarity.

Comment: @TheWolf1494 I've updated the answer. I personally think that you should drop the whole `useEffect`. Do you need the setter from `useState`? If so, what for? I've provided an example scenario for the use of a search filter.

Comment: this doesn't address the question asked at all.  Not even a little bit.

Comment: @BenGlasser Read the full question. Than this full answer. It does address the issues presented. One of the issues is that the state is `undefined` while the data of `useQuery` has already been loaded, which I address. I then beg the question if OP needs to use a state at all and offer alternatives. Finally I suggest to use the `onComplete` which might trigger earlier than `useEffect`. (After the data is loaded but before the render instead of after the render.) Care to elaborate what is missing?